# Одиночный выбор Checkbox в пункте меню

Tags: android, checkbox, android-shared-preferences, android-menu

Я добавил в пункт меню два `checkbox` которые при запуске приложения берут значения из `SharedPeferences`, по умолчанию `false.:`

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    boolean isCheckedR = mPreferences.getBoolean("mode", false);
    boolean isCheckedN = mPreferences.getBoolean("mode", false);

    MenuItem itemR = menu.findItem(R.id.action_read_mode);
    MenuItem itemN = menu.findItem(R.id.action_night_mode);

    itemN.setChecked(isCheckedN);
    itemR.setChecked(isCheckedR);

    return true;
}
```

Далее в `onOptionsItemSelected` я передаю и сохраняю выбранное `true/false` значение.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    int modeR = R.id.action_read_mode;
    int modeN = R.id.action_night_mode;

    if (id == modeR) {
        item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
        mEdit.putBoolean("mode", item.isChecked());

         if (item.isChecked()) {
            // Выполнение кода в случае когда установлена галочка
        } else {
            // Выполнение кода в случае когда галочка снята
        }
    }

    if (id == modeN) {
        item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
        mEdit.putBoolean("mode", item.isChecked());

        if (item.isChecked()) {
            // Выполнение кода в случае когда установлена галочка
        } else {
            // Выполнение кода в случае когда галочка снята
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

В итоге получается что при нажатии на первый бокс, я буду включать режим чтения, а при нажатии на второй, ночной режим. Вопрос возможно ли сделать так, чтобы если выбран один из режимов, по нажатию на другой чтобы первый отключался? То есть, чтобы было невозможно устанавливать состояние `true` обоим `checkbox` включаешь один, отключается другой.

**Дополнение**

Из тех вариантов которые я попробовал, это в частности поместить `item` в `group` и убрать `android:checkable="true"` там образом `Checkbox` стал `Radio Button` и стал одиночным выбором, однако в этом есть проблема. Один из двух изначально должен быть выбран, а мне нужно чтобы пользователь при желании включал и выключал режим чтения/ночной режим, либо как вариант добавить еще один пункт назвав его "стандарт", но я не хочу добавлять еще один пункт. По возможности хотелось бы провернуть это именно с `Checkbox`.
`

Comment: вообще для этого есть RadioGroup из RadioButton. Их можно кастомизировать и под чекбокс, при необходимости.

Comment: Так вы же уже устанавливаете состояние `itemN.setChecked` в `onCreateOptionsMenu`. Что мешает сделать тоже самое и в `onOptionsItemSelected`?

Comment: @pavlofff дополнил вопрос, мне нужно чтобы работало так, есть 2 `checkbox`, нажал на один, включался режим чтения, нажал на другой, режим чтения выключился, включился ночной режим, нажал на него еще раз, он выключился.

Comment: @eugeneek `menu.findItem` не работает в методе `onOptionsItemSelected` и я соответственно изначальное состояние в нем не смог задать, поэтому я поместил в `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: Просто вынесите объявление переменных `MenuItem itemR; MenuItem itemN;` из метода и будете иметь к ним доступ отовсюду внутри класса.

Comment: @pavlofff Можете дать ссылку на пример кастомизации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выносите объявление переменных `MenuItem` из метода в сам класс активити:

```
private MenuItem itemR;
private MenuItem itemN;
```

Инициализируете их, как и раньше, в `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    itemN = menu.findItem(R.id.action_read_mode);
    itemR = menu.findItem(R.id.action_night_mode);

    boolean isCheckedR = mPreferences.getBoolean("mode_r", false);
    boolean isCheckedN = mPreferences.getBoolean("mode_n", false);

    itemN.setChecked(isCheckedN);
    itemR.setChecked(isCheckedR);

    return true;
}
```

И в `onOptionsItemSelected` устанавливаете им значения в зависимости от выбранного пункта:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    boolean isChecked;
    item.setChecked(isChecked = !item.isChecked());

    if (item.getItemId() == itemR.getItemId()) {
        mEdit.putBoolean("mode_r", isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
            itemN.setChecked(false);
            mEdit.putBoolean("mode_n", false);
        }

    } else {
        mEdit.putBoolean("mode_n", isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
            itemR.setChecked(false);
            mEdit.putBoolean("mode_r", false);
        }
    }

    mEdit.apply();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Не работает....

Comment: Придется переводить в `RadioButton` и добавлять еще один `item`.

Comment: Что именно не работает? Специально сделал у себя тестовый проект, на котором этот способ работает.

Comment: Не понятно где сохранять выбранные значения? При нажатии на пункт приложение падает, в логах `Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.view.MenuItem.getItemId()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Ну инициализировать их нужно было, как и до этого. Дополнил ответ. Плюс изменил ваш код с сохранением. До этого вы оба значения записывали в один и тот же ключ `mode`, естественно затирая друг друга. Да и само сохранение не делали. Добавил  `mEdit.apply();`

Comment: Все работает, справился.

Comment: Когда перезапускаю приложение галочки установлены у обоих `checkbox`

Comment: Да, есть такое. Поправил код в ответе.